# How to pass JSON object to Struts2 <s:iterator> tag

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am getting JSON object via ajax call using JQuery. JSON object contains list of model (i.e Bean)

e.g `List<myModel>`

I am using struts2 json plugin.

JSON object as a string looks as given below.

```
{"myList":[{"age":26,"degree":"MCA","fname":"Pravin","id":1,"lname":"Varpe"},
{"age":26,"degree":"MCA","fname":"Pramod","id":2,"lname":"Patil"},
{"age":24,"degree":"B.E","fname":"Atul","id":3,"lname":"Vairale"},
{"age":22,"degree":"M.E","fname":"Sudeep","id":4,"lname":"Masare"},
{"age":21,"degree":"BCS","fname":"Nikhil","id":1,"lname":"Pethe"},
{"age":21,"degree":"MCS","fname":"Abhijeet","id":1,"lname":"Supekar"}]}
```

I want to pass this JSON object to `<s:iterator>` tag as given below

```
<s:iterator value = "myJsonObject">
     <s:property value = "fname"/>
     // properties 
</s:iterator>
```

I can display this JSON object on jsp by iterating it into jquery function & creating html element but I don't want to do that. So is it possible to directly pass JSON to `<s:iterator>` tag anyhow?

Comment: If you don't want to do it in JS why do you return JSON?

Comment: Because I want to use ajax functionality i.e I don't want to reload the page. Is there any another way that i can get a values on JSP from action without reloading the page?

Comment: Return HTML from ajax call not JSON and add it to page.

Comment: How can we send html from Struts2 Action? Can we?

Comment: You are probably doing it already... using `dispatcher` result `<result>/WEB-INF/...</result>`. :)

Comment: But using dispatcher we just redirect to the JSP page where html code is already created. In my case as you said, I need to create & return html code from within action class. How can i do that? And second thing when we use dispatcher, page will reload. Where JSON result type prevents page reload.

Comment: What stops you to return `dispatcher` result from ajax called action?

Comment: I will check it out & get back to you.

Comment: @Aleksandr Thank you very much for your superb guidance. I think i have got the point what you were trying to say. I have successfully passed the `List<myModel>` to the `<s:iterator>` tag by using `dispatcher'. Thanks allot once again.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add your solution as an answer for future visitors.

Comment: Yes Sure. But i will first implement it perfectly in my code by checking all the possible conditions with all pros & cons. Then will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On discussion with @Aleksandr I found the Answer. I am posting it here so that any one facing same problem can get a help form it.

To `<s:iterator>` tag we can not pass JSON object & it's not at all needed. What I had to achieve is to make a ajax call & pass a result to the `<s:iterator>`.

So no need to use a Struts2 json plugin. Simply use `dispatcher` which is default result type of action in Struts2 which returns html. Simple steps are

1. Create separate JSP page say `List.jsp` which will contain `<s:iterator>` tag to which we will pass the result(i.e `List<myModel>` in my case).
2. Give this `List.jsp` as a result page of our action as show below.

   ```
   <s:action name="myAction" class="package.MyClass">
       <result name = "success">List.jsp</result>
   </s:action>
   ```
3. So on making ajax call we will get `List.jsp`(i.e html) as a response. Simply add this response data to the any `div` you want.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get "mylist" Object then you need to iterate through "myList" and then again use JsonObject iterator to get key-value pairs.

```
<s:iterator value="test.get('myList')" var="listJsonArray">
    <s:iterator value="listJsonArray" var="row">  
        <s:iterator value="row" var="jsonObject" > 
            <s:property/>
        </s:iterator> 
    </s:iterator> 
</s:iterator>
```